How can I manage shopping card in client side in ASP.NET
This is my method in User panel after click on Card Icon in header: as you see I read from data  base some data. But I Have a script to handle and manage shop card ,
    [HttpGet("/UserPanel/AddToCart")]
    public async  Task<IActionResult> ShowCart(List<int> chefFoodIds)
    {
       
        var userId = User.GetCurrentUserId();
   
        if (chefFoodIds == null || !chefFoodIds.Any())
        {
            ViewBag.EmptyCartMessage = "You Don't Have any Item To Buy !";
           
        }

        await GetTax();
      
        var cartItems = await _orderService.GetCartItemForShow(chefFoodIds);
        ViewData["CartItemCount"] = cartItems.Sum(item => item.Quantity);


        return View(cartItems);
    }

I want to know If I want to create card and handle the price and quantity, can I do all of these needs without method on database in server side? I mean Can I do it with out database , Just in client side with local storage with java script?
If yes for having first data , to show in User Panel , it does not need to pickup data from data base in first? and can I do it from local storage too?
If yes , how can I handle the view of card and user panel in script?

I want if user click on Shop card Icon, User panel shows to him and Get method need, so how can I show it to users?

Normally, the item inside the shop card is stored inside the server, since store inside the client like cookie it will contain the expire time, if the user exceed the expire time or change a browser which will lead all the data loss which make a bad user experience.

@BrandoZhang so it means you say , it s not good way ? and it s better that I manage it with server ? not in side of client?

the frontend would get the localstorage items via javascript, and then send them with the request.  You should probably send in a POST, but GET should work too as comma-separated values.  Ex: your_url.com?chefFoodIds=12,32,53,345,1  OR each same name:  Ex: your_url.com?chefFoodIds=12&chefFoodIDs=32&chefFoodIDs=53...

though you'll probably need to bind a more complex model and use a POST.  Something that has foodID and QTY.  So bind a List where YourType contains int FoodID and int Quantity...
